# Get the_permanlink () in html and then format in functions.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

Ok I have an issue here which I'm finding really hard to fix. Although I'm guessing it's probably not that complicated.

I'm using wordpress and in my functions.php I have the following:

```
<?php
class EXAMPLE {
$this->url=rawurlencode($url);
}

function DO-SOMETHING() { 
DO-SOMETHING . $this->url);
}
?>
```

Then I call the function in my html:

```
<div>
<?php $obj=new EXAMPLE("www.example.com"); echo $obj->DO-SOMETHING();?>
</div>
```

I need to replace ("www.example.com") with (the_permalink()).
but it doesn't work. Not sure why. I have tried a number of different ways using trial and error, but can't find a solution

Thanks

Comment: For anyone with the same issue, I found the answer here

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397052/get-permalink-for-json-decode-not-working/18436334#18436334][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397052/get-permalink-for-json-decode-not-working/18436334#18436334

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about encoding an URL, the following would do:

```
echo rawurlencode( get_the_permalink() );
```

You could also wrap that in a function:

```
echo myrawurlencode( get_the_permalink() );

function myrawurlencode($url){
    rawurlencode( $url );
}
```

**note: `get_the_permalink()` returns the URL, while `the_permalink()` echoes it directly by default.**

If you're going to use a class, you might want to take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php
and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php first.

Comment: Tried this but doesn't work. The function formats a json return. The full code can be found here [link](http://toolspot.org/script-to-get-shared-count.php).The issue is in the code i can't put get_the_permalink() inside the quotation marks"". If I do it without them, the url doesnt get formatted by the php.

Answer (score 0):

Well like mentioned `the_peramlink()` displays the url using the echo statement, but you could use `get_permalink($id)` which returns the url. WordPress makes sure that the url returned by both functions are escaped and can be used without using the `rawurlencode()` function from PHP.

Unless you need to append something to the permalink you don't need this function and should be just fine with the get_permalink($id) function. You could always check the [get_permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) documentation in the Wordpress codex for more information.