# get_permalink for json_decode not working

Tags: php, json, wordpress, function

This is probably a straight forward fix, but I really can't get it to work. My code reads as follows:

**PHP** (functions.php)

```
<?php
class shareCount {
    private $url,$timeout;

    function __construct($url,$timeout=10) {
        $this->url=rawurlencode($url);
        $this->timeout=$timeout;
    }

    function get_tweets() { 
        $json_string = $this->file_get_contents_curl(
            'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $this->url
        );
        $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
        return isset($json['count'])?intval($json['count']):0;
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see there are two functions above: one which gets the link to be decoded and another to decode the json information and return a digit.

I call the two functions in my html as follows:

```
<div>

<?php
$obj=new shareCount("get_permalink()");
echo $obj->get_tweets();
?>

</div>
```

The issue I have is that in the html/php, where i call the functions, `"get_permalink"` will not work inside the the `""` marks. If i remove the quotation marks it also doesn't work. The only way this setup seems to work is if a link is manually placed inside the quotes.

I need to use `get_permalink()` or something similar to pull the current post url and then add the `json_decode` function to it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `get_permalink()` without quotes around it? does it actually give you a valid URL? (also valid for the service!)

Comment: Try to pass the `post_id` in `get_permalink()` .

Comment: It gives a valid url, but from my understanding the php script for the json decode won't process it. I belive this is because its not in the quotation marks. If it is in them then its not php and returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue , I have found the solution to this problem. It took a while but i finally fixed it. The final code is as follows:

PHP (functions.php)

```
<?php

    function get_tweets($url) {
        $url = get_permalink($post->ID)
        $json_string = $this->file_get_contents_curl(
            'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url
        );
        $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
        return isset($json['count'])?intval($json['count']):0;
    }
}
?>
```

And call the function in HTML as follows:

```
<div>

<?php
echo get_tweets($url);
?>

</div>
```

Basically you need to specify that the php function "get_tweets" is a url. Then specifiy that url as "$url = get_permalink($post->ID). Then when you call the function in html just write echo get_tweets ($url).

Answer (score 0):

$this->file_get_contents_curl replaced file_get_contents

Comment: This doesnt work. The problem is that I can't use get_permalink inside quotation marks